# How do I use UglifyJS from an Ant build?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I'm looking to implement UglifyJS into my Ant build process to replace YUI Compressor. What are the basic steps to get started?

Comment: A quick fix would be to use this https://github.com/yuanyan/UglifyJS-java .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After having installed uglifyjs with -g option:

```
npm install uglify-js -g
```

Use ant like that:

```
<exec dir="${build_dir}" executable="uglifyjs.cmd">
  <arg line="-o jquery.min.js --unsafe -nc jquery.src.js"/>
</exec>
```

On Windows you use uglifyjs.cmd, and uglifyjs on linux. You can define a conditional property if you want to keep the build.xml cross-platform.

See https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/#usage for all arguments

Comment: Note that I did some tests and YUI is not very good at shrinking.
Closure Compiler and UglifyJS are equivalent unless you use UglifyJS --unsafe, in which case UglifyJS is better

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -> https://github.com/yuanyan/UglifyJS-java

Comment: Sure wish this were released under a license of some sort. As far as I can tell it's unlicensed, and therefore potentially proprietary.

Comment: @Gus According to Github's terms of use, anything hosted there for free is "viewable and forkable". So, as long as you don't release the UglifyJS-java code in your project, you should be fine.

Comment: Exactly... not much good to view and fork if one can't actually use it for anything.